# How to remove default header for Ktor client 2.0.0

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, ktor-client

Ktor v2.0.0 for Android.

The default ktor header "Accept" just overwrites my "Accept" header.

This is the way I am initializing my HttpClient:

```
  HttpClient(Android) {
    defaultRequest {
        header("Key", BuildConfigCore.API_KEY)
        header("Accept", "application/vnd.***.mobile-v8+json")
      
        host = hostAddress
        url.protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
    }
    install(Logging) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
    }
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson()
    }
    expectSuccess = false
}
```

But when i check with Charles interceptor, my headers looks like:
[image]

I have that

> application/json

which overwrites my `application/vnd...` value.

Is it any way to replace the default "Accept" header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `Accept` header from the `defaultRequest` block and register your content type for the `GsonConverter` instead of using the default `application/json` content type.

```
val client = HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson(ContentType("application", "vnd.***.mobile-v8+json"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to just not send it at all?